# How can I (faster) scroll through different directories with IrfanView?

Tags: scrolling, irfanview

I would like to faster change a directory if I scroll through the pictures in different directories.

Example:

```
C:\Temp\Folder1\Picture1.jpg
C:\Temp\Folder1\Picture2.jpg
C:\Temp\Folder1\Picture3.jpg
C:\Temp\Folder2\Picture4.jpg
C:\Temp\Folder2\Picture5.jpg
C:\Temp\Folder2\Picture6.jpg
```

Is it possible to setup IrfanView in a way, that after showing Picture3.jpg it changes the path "one up", then find the next folder (\Folder2 in the above example) and then show Picture4.jpg automagically?

I know that I can achieve that with the cursor keys and the activated "Browse subfolder" dialog box. It would save a lot of time to scroll through pictures without a manual selection of the next directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in **Irfanview's Thumbnails mode** (it can be opened when watching an image with key 'T'):

- go to your parent folder (C:\Temp\ in your example) in left Thumbnails' navigator
- in **Options** menu, just select "**Load thumbs from all subfolders**"
- all images will be loaded on right view, but you can now click on any of them without waiting for it to be completely loaded, and traverse all of them with Page Down / Page Up.